# Mass Updating a single column based on ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I keep track of users and their activity, assigning a numerical value for what they do, storing it in a cache and updating the DB every 2 hours logging their activity.

I usually have about 10000 users during this period, all with different activity points - so for example, I would have to update 10000 rows of `activity` column in the table `users` based on column `user_id` every 2 hours, with something simple like `activity = activity + 500` per row.

What would be an effective way to do so? Obviously it would be really slow if I sent a query each time for each user, some methods I researched was using case, but ultimately 10,000 cases would also take really long and would be inefficient as well. I'm sure there's a good method to do so that I haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you need this optimization? 10,000 users over 2 hours is only about 2 users per second. Consider instead simply inserting activities into a user_activity table as needed. Inserting rows into a different table, rather than updating users, avoids needing write locks on user rows. Such an "insert-only" table should perform well.

Second, 2 hours between updates seems excessive. The win of caching is to avoid a flurry of update queries per second, but the benefits rapidly drop off. Try 1 minute or even less. This will reduce the size of the update, greatly simplify the update process, and avoid possibly locking a bunch of rows.

---

If you do need this optimization, you can do it by updating from a temp table.

1. Make a temp table with user ID and activity count.
2. [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) your cached user IDs and activity counts into the temp table.
3. update from the temp table.

The update would look something like this...

```
update users u
set activity = u.activity + tmp.activity
from tmp_user_activity tmp
where tmp.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: You have to realize that if I updated every minute, the amount of activity would greatly increase - this is why I'm doing it in 2 hour intervals. 

For example, I have 200,000 users in total. I say 10,000 updates per 2 hours as each activity as I expect around 10,000 different users to be active within those 2 hour sessions. This means that all "activity points" are compiled into "1 query", as they could do 500 activities for 500 points within those 2 hours. If I have it every request, it would be something more like 200 req/sec.

Comment: @Lego490 If you've already done benchmarks and found the complexity of the optimization necessary, try the bulk update I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a values list in order to create a virtual user-supplied table, and then do an update with a join to that table.

```
update users set activity=activity+t.y 
   from (values (1,5),(2,9),(3,19) /*, ...*/ ) t(id,y) 
where users.user_id=t.id;
```